# Bokeh Slider Not Updating in JupyterLab

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I am running an adapted version of https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9431

Bokeh 2.2.3
Python 3.8.6
JupyterLab 2.2.9

In JupyterLab, it displays just fine, but it is not updating the color bar and image when the Range Slider is adjusted. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import Row
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper, BasicTicker, ColorBar, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import RangeSlider
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", low=0, high=1)

figure = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))
img = figure.image(image=[data], color_mapper=color_mapper,
                   dh=[1.0], dw=[1.0], x=[0], y=[0])

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, ticker= BasicTicker(),
                     location=(0,0))

figure.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
  
range_slider = RangeSlider(start=data.min(), end=data.max(), value=(data.min(), data.max()), step=.1, title="Stuff", width=400)
range_slider.js_on_change("value", CustomJS(code="""
    range = cb_obj.range
    img.glyph.color_mapper.low = cb_obj.value[0];
    img.glyph.color_mapper.high = cb_obj.value[1];    
"""))


show(Row(figure, range_slider))
```

Comment: Did you install the required jupyterlab extension? https://github.com/bokeh/jupyter_bokeh#jupyter_bokeh

Comment: All my other bokeh plots have worked. But just installed jupyter_bokeh now, installed correctly, and it still doesn't update the plot when i use the slider.

Comment: Make sure you clear all existing output cells, if this is an old notebook. Also `jupyter_bokeh` can be pip/conda installed starting with Bokeh 2.3. If you have an older version you will need to use the old `labextension` install method. (Aside: please always, *always* provide relevant version information up front on every question)

Comment: Are there any errors in your browsers JS console?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the browser JS console you can see the relevant error messages, e.g. "range is not defined". You need to pass any objects you want to refer to in the JS code in the `args` paramter of `CustomJS`. This is described [in the docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html?highlight=customjs#customjs-callbacks). Here is a working version (tested w/ Bokeh 2.3, Jupyterlab >=3):

```py
cb = CustomJS(args=dict(slider=range_slider, glyph=img.glyph), code="""
    glyph.color_mapper.low = slider.value[0];
    glyph.color_mapper.high = slider.value[1];    
""")

range_slider.js_on_change("value", cb)
```

[image]

Also, FYI it's generally a bad idea to shadow existing function names:

```
figure = figure(...) # BAD, now you can never call figure again
```

Comment: Wow that fixed it alright! That's pretty cool. Thank you! Also ya that figure comment is good. I edited the OP to include Python, Bokeh, and JupyterLab versions. Will certainly do that going forward.